# Laravel link to destroy route not defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes

[image]Heloo guys i want to destroy a model in laravel.All it's ok but is giving me the "Route [finance/loans.destroy,$loan->id] not defined."
can you help me?
This is the button that delete an element:

```
<td><button href="{{route('finance/loans.destroy,$loan->id') }}" id="btnExc" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" accesskey="x" hidden><br>Delete</button></td>
```

These are the routes:

```
|        | POST      | finance/loans             | loans.store      | App\Http\Controllers\loanController@store                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | finance/loans             | loans.index      | App\Http\Controllers\loanController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | finance/loans/create      | loans.create     | App\Http\Controllers\loanController@create                             | web,auth     |
|        | PUT|PATCH | finance/loans/{loan}      | loans.update     | App\Http\Controllers\loanController@update                             | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | finance/loans/{loan}      | loans.show       | App\Http\Controllers\loanController@show                               | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE    | finance/loans/{loan}      | loans.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\loanController@destroy                            | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | finance/loans/{loan}/edit | loans.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\loanController@edit
```

The route declaration:

```
Route::resource('/finance/loans','loanController');
```

Comment: Links are automatically sent to the server with a GET response, and `loans.destroy` is defined as a `DELETE` route. You'll want to send a form request with the DELETE method instead. Also, it's defined as `loans.destroy`, not `finance/loans.destroy`

Comment: You should provide us also the routes file.

Comment: i tried with loans.destroy and it;s giving me same error.I think i don;t declare the route good.And i tried with finance/loans.show and loans.show where show is defiend as a get route and same error.

Comment: Could you post a complete form you're calling with the button?

Comment: i don't have a form .I pass the id thru the href .You have a screenshot

Comment: @Andrei , if you pass through url, you will allway be calling `GET` METHOD instead of `DELETE` since your concerned route is the one with `DELETE` method

Comment: that was the problem.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should send a form (js or not) with delete method in laravel way (`_method='DELETE'`). 
Check this

```
<td>
<form action="{{ route('loans.destroy', $loan->id) }}" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
<input type="submit"  value="Delete" name="Delete" id="btnExc" 
        class="btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" accesskey="x"/>

</form>
</td>
```

Comment: Now it works with the form.Thank you.I saw a video on youtube with passing in href the route and that's why i made it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the route wrong, and have a missing quote:

```
<td>
<button href="{{ route('loans.destroy', $loan->id) }}" id="btnExc" 
        class="btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" accesskey="x" hidden>
    <br>Delete</button>
</td>
```

**EDIT**

You can't get to the `DELETE` http request if you don't post it through a form. If you want to use button to delete the model directly you will have to make your own method and route:

```
Route:get('finance/loans/destroyMe/{id}', 'loanController@destroyMe');
```

and then in the controller:

```
public function destroyMe($id)
{
    SomeModel::destroy($id);
}
```

This is only stubbing out the code, didn't test it out, but this is the basic principle

Comment: i saw the  ' mising and i put it in the code. just saying above i tried "loans.destroy"and nothing

Comment: You still didn't post a complete form. Route is obviously declared fine when you're getting the output with `route:list` :)